# Exercise about inequality - Taylor polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider a function defined in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(3)}$ is continuous in $[0,1].$ Suppose that $f(0)=f′(0)=f′′(0)=f′(1)=f′′(1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f^{(3)}(c)\geq 24$.

The question was originally posted here [Inequality related to Taylor polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297232/inequality-related-to-taylor-polynomial/3297278)

But there was some mistakes in the statement. Thus maybe it is better to write as an new question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Err.... how is that not the exact **same** statement? You edited there, and then posted it back here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality related to Taylor polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297232/inequality-related-to-taylor-polynomial)

Comment: (What I mean is -- either you don't edit the statement there (as it invalidated the current answers) and post a new question with the corrected statement; or you edit it there (as you just did) and don't post it again. Doing what you have done (edit there but still repost) is bad on all aspects.

Comment: @ClementC. Calm down. OP had edited the other post. When the other post was answered, the problem went like $f(c)\geq24$ without the third derivative. But for the OP it was too late to correct that problem. So he/she asked a new question here.

Comment: @FengShao So, read my comment. The correct thing to do is then to leave the mistake in the statement there (people spent time to give counterexamples, after all), and post the correct statement here. Not both invalidate the answers there *and* repost here.

I am calm, by the way. Are you?

Comment: @ClementC. I agree with you. I have edited the other post to match the answers there, waiting for the OP to review my edit.

Comment: @FengShao I suggest trying the edit again but this time in the comment link to this question and summarize the reasons given above. I regret that I did not have this information when I reviewed the edit, because I assumed the OP was trying to correct the question _without_ also reposting it, which also would have been a reasonable course of action at the time. (But I think the door has since been shut on that.)

Comment: @DavidK I’ve done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Taylor’s formula to obtain
$$f(\frac12)=f(0)+\frac12f’(0)+\frac{f’’(0)}{2!}(\frac12)^2+\frac{f’’’(\xi_1)}{3!}(\frac12)^3,$$
$$f(\frac12)=f(1)-\frac12f’(1)+\frac{f’’(1)}{2!}(\frac12)^2-\frac{f’’’(\xi_2)}{3!}(\frac12)^3,$$
where $\xi_1\in[0,1/2]$ and $\xi_2\in[1/2,1]$.
Doing the subtraction we get 
$$f’’’(\xi_1)+f’’’(\xi_2)=48,$$
so one of them will be no less than $24$.